# Should I use a high pass filter or low pass filter to enhance the features for image splicing detection?

Tags: image-processing, highpass-filter

I'm recently learning image splicing detection.I've already known image splicing can bring some abrupt changes to an image,which generate the sharp edges.And sharp edges correspond to high frequency.
And I want to extract features from images for splicing detection.In my opinion,I should use a high-pass filter to enhance the edges,but I've read some papers which mentioned using a low-pass filter for gradient detection techniques applied in discontinuity detection.
Now I am very bothered with this.Which kind of filters should I use?I would really appreciate if someone can help me!

Comment: This question might be better of on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree - it might be better on the other forum - but it is a programming question, and people here might be able to help, so let's not reject it.